# Django Rest Framework djoser activation problem

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I know there is lots of questions like this problem but i really need your help.I am trying to activate account with email verification but i cannot activate the account the link that i am sending,is not activating the account.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('auth/', include('authapp.urls'))]
```

This is my main url.Inside authapp i wrote these urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include('djoser.urls')),
path('', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
path('activation/<str:uid>/<str:token>/', UserActivationView.as_view()),]
```

My settings are like this:

```
 DJOSER = {
'LOGIN_FIELD':'email',
'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE':True,
'SERIALIZERS':{
    'user_create':'authapp.serializer.UserCreateSerializer',
    'user': 'authapp.serializer.UserCreateSerializer',


},
"ACTIVATION_URL": 'auth/request_activate/{uid}/{token}',
"SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL": True,
}
```

And this is my view.py:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

import requests


    class UserActivationView(APIView):
        def get (self, request, uid, token):
            protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
            web_url = protocol + request.get_host()
            post_url = web_url + "/auth/users/activation/"
            post_data = {'uid': uid, 'token': token}
            result = requests.post(post_url, data = post_data)
            content = result.text()
            return Response(content)
```

I tried almost every solution but it didn't work.I hope you can help me guys.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"ACTIVATION_URL": 'auth/activation/{uid}/{token}',
```

This is the correct form.